# Use a pre-populated sqllite db file with Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Is there a way to use a pre-populated sqlite db file like "xyz.db" with Android Room. I went through couple of posts but still not able to figure out a robust solution.

The db file **"xyx.db"** is located in the **assets/databases** folder.

Also I want to know if Android Room is the right choice for an app which uses DB only for read. There would be no writes to the DB. Please suggest any alternate approach to solve this kind of problem with an ORM solution.

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Looking for some out of the box solution provided by Room. Maybe through the migration route.

Comment: `RoomDatabase.Builder#openHelperFactory` is out of the box solution

Comment: I also had same question. Take a look at Commonware's solution here, https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.6/General/AssetRoom . No need to copy the db file.